# Соединение Android с сервером

Tags: android, сокет, сеть

Разрабатываю небольшую систему мониторинга. Сервер должен каждые 3 секунды отправлять данные датчика на клиент (Android 4.2) через интернет (на клиенте 3G).

Как организовать канал связи? Есть варианты:

1. Постоянное соединение через сокет.
2. GET запросы с телефона на сервер.

Телефон не должен уходить в сон. Примерное время работы - 8 ч/сутки (будет подключён PowerBank).

Что лучше в плане энергопотребления? И есть ли что-то ещё более эффективное?

Comment: а телефон будет отображать полученные данные?

Comment: Может для передачи данных использовать обычные пуши?

Answer (score 1):

Раз в 3 секунды - это очень часто, практически непрерывно. Единственная оптимизация энергопотребления, о которой можно говорить в этом случае, это погасить экран.

Дальше читайте про [WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu), [Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) и запрос в "белый список". Коротко:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
else {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Дальше, раз в 3 секунды может не получится - IP не дает гарантий скорости и доставки. Сразу продумайте, что должно быть с вашими данными, если была задержка доставки на 30 секунд? Если сервер был недоступен 2 минуты? От этого зависит выбор протокола. В простейшем случае вам подойдет или собственный протокол поверх TCP, либо готовая реализация [WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket). HTTP для такой частоты запросов - плохая идея.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую `POST + JSON`. Я бы использовал эти технологии. Отправлять по событию (в зависимости от вашего проэкта). По энергопотреблению думаю что картина будет не особо разная. То есть при разных вариантах (`GET`,`POST`,`Socket`) по времени разрядки думаю что картина будет приблизительно одинакова. Здесь даже влияет не столько соединение, сколько запуск системных служб подключения к интернету 3G. То есть наиболее экономную картину энергопотребления можно будет увидеть при минимальном количестве запросов (к примеру если слать запрос каждые 5 секунд или 10, то разница будет существенна). То есть если служба интернета (3G) ушла в сон (к примеру) мы очень экономим батарею. Для существенной экономии энергии нужно исходить из изменения значения датчика (если есть такая возможность), но это зависит от типа датчика. Можно ведь в зависимости от изменений датчика в сам ответ с сервера `JSON` (к примеру) вставить переменную **через сколько секунд выслать следуйщий запрос**, это даст возможность минимизировать количество запросов и создаст существенную экономию батареи (если параметры датчика не менялись три минуты то зачем делать опрос каждые три секунды). То есть уменьшать количество запуска самой интернет службы `Android`.

**Если тип датчика и самого проэкта дает возможность уменьшить количество запросов** (и использования интернет службы андроид), **то это существенно увеличит время работы батареи.** 
Если же нужно просто передавать одну переменную каждые строго 3 сек, то сещественной разницы при разном подключении вы не увидите, для андроид системы все равно чем вы запусквете интернет (имеет большое значение сколько раз в минуту или час, в плане энергопотребления).